# Page redirection for mailto and tel links on Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, mailto, tel

I have a working Cordova iOS app. Now I am working on an Android app. I have a "contact us" page where I have a link:

```
 <a id="lnkEmail" style="border: none;box-shadow: none;text-align: left;" data-role="button"  href="#">  support@website.com          </a>

 $('#lnkEmail').on('click',function(){
         document.location.href = "mailto:support@site.com";
    });
```

The page is redirected to a "webpage not available" error page while the link opens in an email client. How do I stop page redirection? I have tried:

```
 <a style="border: none;box-shadow: none;text-align: left;" data-role="button"  **href="mailto:support@site.com"** target="_top">support@site.com </a>
```

As well as:

```
 <a id="lnkEmail" style="border: none;box-shadow: none;text-align: left;" data-role="button"  **href="javascript: void(0);"**>support@site.com</a>  support@site.com         </a>
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug on how the mailto is handled and it try to navigate to the page before loading the email client.

You can try using [inAppBrowser plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser)

```
window.open('mailto:support@site.com', '_system');
```